# PostgreSQL: Get last updates by joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables that I need to join to get the last/latest update in the 2nd table based on valid rows in the 1st table.

Code below is en example.

**Table 1: Registered users**
This table contains a list of users registered in the system. 
When a user gets registered it gets added into this table. A user is registered with a name, and a registration time. 
A user can get de-registered from the system. When this is done, the de-registration column gets updated to the time that the user was removed. If this value is NULL, it means that the user is still registered.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    entry_idx   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT NOT NULL,
    reg_time    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    dereg_time  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL  
);
```

**Table 2: User updates**
This table contains updates on the users. Each time a user changes a property (example position) the change gets stored in this table. No updates must be removed since there is a requirement to keep history in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_updates (
    entry_idx   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT NOT NULL,
    position    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    time        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

**Required output**
So given the above information, I need to get a new table that contains only the last update for the current registered users.

**Test Data**
The following data can be used as test data for the above tables:

```
-- Register 3 users
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('Person1');
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('Person2');
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('Person3');
-- Add some updates for all users
INSERT INTO user_updates(name, position) VALUES ('Person1', 0);
INSERT INTO user_updates(name, position) VALUES ('Person1', 1);
INSERT INTO user_updates(name, position) VALUES ('Person1', 2);
INSERT INTO user_updates(name, position) VALUES ('Person2', 1);
INSERT INTO user_updates(name, position) VALUES ('Person3', 1);
-- Unregister the 2nd user
UPDATE users SET dereg_time = NOW() WHERE name = 'Person2';
```

From the above, I want the last updates for Person 1 and Person 3.

**Failed attempt**
I have tried using joins and other methods but the results are not what I am looking for. The question is almost the same as one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464365/postgresql-join-2-tables). I have used the solution in answer 1 and it does give the correct answer, but it takes too long to get too the answer in my system.

Based on the above link I have created the following query that 'works':

```
SELECT
  t1.*
  , t2.*
FROM
  users t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
      t.*,
      row_number()
  OVER (
      PARTITION BY
        t.name
      ORDER BY t.entry_idx DESC
      ) rn
  FROM user_updates t
  ) t2
ON
  t1.name = t2.name
AND
  t2.rn = 1
WHERE
  t1.dereg_time IS NULL;
```

**Problem**
The problem with the above query is that it takes very long to complete. Table 1 contains a small list of users, while table 2 contains a huge amount of updates. I think that the query might be inefficient in the way that it handles the 2 tables (based on my limited understanding of the query). From pgAdmin's explain it does a lot of sorting and aggregation on the updates 1st before joining with the registered table.

**Question**
How can I formulate a query to efficiently and fast get the latest updates for registered users?

Comment: Do you have an index on `user_updates.name`? Possibly an index on `user_updates (name, entry_idx)` could help.

Comment: I have added indexes but it does not make a noticeable difference.But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL have a special `distinct on` syntax for such type of queries:

```
select distinct on(t1.name)
--it's better to specify columns explicitly, * just for example
    t1.*, t2.*           
from users as t1
    left outer join user_updates as t2 on t2.name = t1.name
where t1.dereg_time is null
order by t1.name, t2.entry_idx desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b17b8/3)</kbd>**

you can try it, but for me your query should work fine too.

Comment: It does look like this could be more efficient but it does not return the last update in the updates table, is there perhaps something that I should add to get it to do this?

Comment: by 'last update' you mean record from updates table with highest time?

Comment: highest entry_idx. some updates can have the same time thus highest time is not always a valid assumption.

Comment: changed a query - you have to order by `entry_idx desc` then

Comment: I most of the queries tested gives the correct answer but each option takes way too long.

My solution was to add a table in the database that gets updated each time a user makes an update. This way there is always an up to date table that I can just query with a normal SELECT. It does make each insert a bit slower (have not benchmarked this) but overall it gives the best performance.

Comment: @TheBadger do you have indexes on name field in users and users_updates?

Answer (score 0):

I am using q1 to get the last update of each user. Then joining with users to remove entries that have been deregistered. Then joining with q2 to get rest of user_update fields.

```
select users.*,q2.* from users
join
(select name,max(time) t from user_updates group by name) q1
on users.name=q1.name 
join user_updates q2 on q1.t=q2.time and q1.name=q2.name
where
users.dereg_time is null
```

(I haven't tested it. have edited some things)

Comment: I will test this shortly, but from your explanation it feels inefficient: Getting 1st the latest updates does work for users removed, which is not needed.

Comment: but you join with users where users.dereg_time is null. (this "where clause" could be inside the "one clause"). please let me know, when you test.

Comment: Still need to test...
Some numbers:
# rows in users: 42 000
# registered users: 6
# rows in updates: 13 000 000
# updates in last 5 minutes: 40 000

_PS_ My example is just an example, my real system is not about users.

So from this to first get the last updates of all updates might waste time.

edit: formatting

Comment: well, the query q1 should return just 42000 rows (as many as users). then you join with users, excluding the de-registered ones. so temporary result is less than 42000 rows. and then joining with user updates to get more info (still same rows as before). Anyhow, when you test it send me feedback with running time.

Comment: I have tested the query, I had to update the max(time) to max(entry_idx) since time is not a valid representation of the latest one, although one would assume it is. But the query still executes in about the same time as my original query (8s).

Comment: i cannot think anything smarter right now. what if you remove the where clause and add it after the first "on clause". i mean: 

---on users.name=q1.name and users.dereg_time is null---