# copy branch of tree in table with REFERENCES

Tags: postgresql, tree

I have table with tree data as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025154/postgresql-copy-data-within-the-tree-table). @Branko Dimitrijevic gave a great answer. But I have other table with foreign key on
table with tree data.
In my case other table:

```
CREATE TABLE TT(
  tt_id SERIALPRIMARY KEY,
  tt_value VARCHAR(50),
  t1_id int REFERENCES t1(id)
);
```

How copy branch with tree data and data in other table?

Comment: What is table `t1` ? Please add sample data and your intended result to your question.

Comment: you may see this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025154/postgresql-copy-data-within-the-tree-table

Comment: Yes, I even commented on it, eight years ago.